# How to load layer from geo server to google maps java script api?

Tags: geoserver, javascript, layers, google-maps-api

i am tring to add geoserver layer to google maps js api.

geoserver installed in local machine its running on local host.

layer is alredy there in Geoserver when insatlled.

i tried some code. its not showing the data and no errors in conslole also.

here my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

        <title>MAP</title>
        <style>
            html,
            body {
                    height: 100%;
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                    }
            #map,
            #pano {
                    float: left;
                    height: 100%;
                    width: 50%;
                    }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <div id="map1"></div>
        <div id="pano"></div>
        <script>
            function myMap() {
                var mapProp = {
                center:{ lat:40.776676  ,  lng:  -73.971321 },
                zoom: 16,
                };

            }

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapProp);

            // map.data.loadGeoJson('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/tiger/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=tiger%3Atiger_roads&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application%2Fjson')
            //       var georssLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
            // url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms/reflect?layers=tiger:tiger_roads&format=kml'
            var censusLayer = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
                getTileUrl: function (coord, zoom) {
                    // Compose URL for overlay tile
                    var s = Math.pow(2, zoom);
                    var twidth = 256;
                    var theight = 256;

                    //latlng bounds of the 4 corners of the google tile
                    //Note the  coord passed in represents the top left hand (NW) corner of the tile.
                    var gBl = map.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(coord.x * twidth / s, (coord.y + 1) * theight / s)); // bottom left / SW
                    var gTr = map.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point((coord.x + 1) * twidth / s, coord.y * theight / s)); // top right / NE

                    // Bounding box coords for tile in WMS pre-1.3 format (x,y)

                    var bbox = parseFloat(gBl.lat()) + "," + parseFloat(gBl.lng()) + "," + parseFloat(gTr.lat()) + "," + parseFloat(gTr.lng());

                    //base WMS URL
                    var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/tiger/wms?";

                    url += "&service=WMS";           //WMS service
                    url += "&version=1.1.0";         //WMS version
                    url += "&request=GetMap";        //WMS operation
                    url += "&layers=tiger_roads"; //WMS layers to draw
                    url += "&styles=";               //use default style
                    url += "&format=image/png";      //image format
                    url += "&TRANSPARENT=TRUE";      //only draw areas where we have data
                    url += "&srs=EPSG:4326";         //projection WGS84
                    url += "&bbox=" + bbox;          //set bounding box for tile
                    url += "&width=256";             //tile size used by google
                    url += "&height=256";
                    //url += "&tiled=true";
                    return url;                 //return WMS URL for the tile
                },
                tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
                opacity: 0.85,
                isPng: true
            });

            // add WMS layer to map
            map.overlayMapTypes.push(censusLayer);
        </script>

        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB41DRUbKWJHPxaFjMAwdrzWzbVKartNGg&callback=myMap"></script>
    </body>
</html>

what mistake i did? how to add layer rom geo server?
```